# C++ Client for external server & Server for external clients simultaneously with boost::asio coroutine

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, coroutine, c++-coroutine

Is it possible to create a single-thread process with a client AND a server running in parallel and communicating between them?

I have an scenario where I need to be both client and server and we can receive/send data in any possible direction.

- Server (PORT A) -> **APP(client-> process message and send to ->server (PORT B))** -> ClientA
- Server (PORT A) <- **APP(client<- process message and send to <-server (PORT B))** <- ClientA
- Server (PORT A) -> **APP(client-> process message and send to** to Server (PORT A)
- ClientA -> **APP(server(PORT B)-> process message and send to** to Client A

I've been trying to modify the examples using boost::asio coroutines provided in the examples and add a client in the io_context or on a separate io_context, but I am struggling with it.

I tried having the client and the server in separate threads, but I am having problems with concurrency as well... Any idea or snippet will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the concurrency problems you were having, and why you need a single-threaded process? Did you have troubles with thread communication mechanisms? Are you facing hardware constraints?

Comment: What does your notation with APP and -> arrows mean? It's not obvious to me what it all means, and there are missing parentheses to make it more confusing.

Comment: I don't have hardware constraints but thought it would be easier to handle in one thread since I struggle with concurrency... By APP I meant the application I intend to do. Receive/Send data from/to an external server and and external client, do some data treatment and send it back to the same device or to others.

Comment: The arrows meant the direction of the message. Sorry I didn't explain myself very well... Basically sometimes I need to receieve data from a server and reply to the server or send it to other clients, and sometimes I need to receive data from a client and send it to the server or reply to the same client, so my idea was to create an application with a server listening on one port for clients to connect and a client connecting to the external server in another port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an scenario where I need to be both client and server and we can receive/send data in any possible direction.

This is pretty standard for a networked application.

The chat server seems a good example to start with (since it does send/receive in all directions): https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp11_examples.chat

Now, as barebones example of a server that also initiates outgoing connections:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Wbxxm4omfMszTiDV)**

Let's create a server that spawns an async session for each accepted
connection. Each session is a "reverse echo" service.

```
// echo server, multi-client
spawn(io, [&io](ba::yield_context yc) {
    tcp::acceptor acc(io, {{}, 6868});
    acc.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));

    while (true) {
        tcp::socket s(io);
        acc.async_accept(s, yc);
        spawn(yc, [s = std::move(s)]
            (ba::yield_context yc) mutable {
            log("Connection from ", s.remote_endpoint());
            std::string msg;
            while (auto n = async_read_until(s, ba::dynamic_buffer(msg), "\n", yc)) {
                std::string_view vw(msg.data(), n);
                vw.remove_suffix(1); // leave '\n'
                log("Responding to ", std::quoted(vw));

                std::reverse(msg.data(), msg.data() + vw.size());

                async_write(s, ba::buffer(msg, n), yc);
                msg = msg.substr(n);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Simultaneously, let's run 5 clients. For want of an external server, we'll just make them connect to our own server.

That allows us to have a self-contained demo, and will prove that the single-threading is not leading to any blocking.

```
// a random client, let's make it connect to our own server, just for this demo
for (auto client_id = 0; client_id<5; ++client_id) {
    spawn(io,
        [&io, delay, client_id, log=logger("client #" + std::to_string(client_id))]
        (ba::yield_context yc) {
            tcp::resolver r(io);
            tcp::socket s(io);
            async_connect(s, r.async_resolve("127.0.0.1", "6868", yc), yc);

            while (true) {
                delay(yc);
                ba::streambuf buf;
                std::ostream(&buf)
                    << "Hello from client #" << client_id << "\n";

                async_write(s, buf, yc);

                std::string response;
                async_read_until(s, ba::dynamic_buffer(response), "\n", yc);
                if (!response.empty())
                    response.pop_back();

                log("Received response ", std::quoted(response));
            }
        });
}
```

Where `delay` is a random delay (500..1500ms):

```
auto delay = [&io](ba::yield_context yc) {
    ba::steady_timer(io, 500ms + (prng() % 1000) * 1ms)
        .async_wait(yc);
};
```

We run the whole program for 3 seconds, and quit:

```
io.run_for(3s);
logger("main")("Bye");
```

Prints

```
at     0ms  session #0  Connection from 127.0.0.1:51024
at     1ms  session #1  Connection from 127.0.0.1:51026
at     1ms  session #2  Connection from 127.0.0.1:51028
at     1ms  session #3  Connection from 127.0.0.1:51030
at     1ms  session #4  Connection from 127.0.0.1:51032
at   831ms  session #3  Responding to "Hello from client #3"
at   831ms  client #3   Received response "3# tneilc morf olleH"
at  1148ms  session #4  Responding to "Hello from client #4"
at  1148ms  client #4   Received response "4# tneilc morf olleH"
at  1196ms  session #1  Responding to "Hello from client #1"
at  1196ms  client #1   Received response "1# tneilc morf olleH"
at  1327ms  session #0  Responding to "Hello from client #0"
at  1327ms  client #0   Received response "0# tneilc morf olleH"
at  1401ms  session #2  Responding to "Hello from client #2"
at  1401ms  client #2   Received response "2# tneilc morf olleH"
at  1446ms  session #3  Responding to "Hello from client #3"
at  1446ms  client #3   Received response "3# tneilc morf olleH"
at  1836ms  session #4  Responding to "Hello from client #4"
at  1836ms  client #4   Received response "4# tneilc morf olleH"
at  2163ms  session #0  Responding to "Hello from client #0"
at  2163ms  client #0   Received response "0# tneilc morf olleH"
at  2382ms  session #2  Responding to "Hello from client #2"
at  2383ms  client #2   Received response "2# tneilc morf olleH"
at  2426ms  session #3  Responding to "Hello from client #3"
at  2426ms  client #3   Received response "3# tneilc morf olleH"
at  2444ms  session #4  Responding to "Hello from client #4"
at  2444ms  client #4   Received response "4# tneilc morf olleH"
at  2579ms  session #1  Responding to "Hello from client #1"
at  2580ms  client #1   Received response "1# tneilc morf olleH"
at  3002ms  main    Bye
```

### Full Listing

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Wbxxm4omfMszTiDV)**

```
#include <boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp>
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>
#define BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::tcp;

using namespace std::literals;

static auto const now = &std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
static auto const start = now();

auto logger(std::string name) {
    return [name](auto const&... args) {
        ((std::cout << "at" << std::setw(6) << (now() - start)/1ms << "ms\t"
                    << name << "\t") 
            << ... << args) << std::endl;
    };
}

int main() {
    ba::io_context io;

    static std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device{}() };

    // insert random async delays
    auto delay = [&io](auto yc) {
        ba::steady_timer(io, 500ms + (prng() % 1000) * 1ms)
            .async_wait(yc);
    };

    // echo server, multi-client
    spawn(io, [&io, log=logger("accept")](ba::yield_context yc) {
        tcp::acceptor acc(io, {{}, 6868});
        acc.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));

        auto num_clients = 0;
        while (true) {
            tcp::socket s(io);
            acc.async_accept(s, yc);
            spawn(yc, [s = std::move(s), log=logger("session #" + std::to_string(num_clients++))]
                (ba::yield_context yc) mutable {
                log("Connection from ", s.remote_endpoint());
                std::string msg;
                while (auto n = async_read_until(s, ba::dynamic_buffer(msg), "\n", yc)) {
                    std::string_view vw(msg.data(), n);
                    vw.remove_suffix(1); // leave '\n'
                    log("Responding to ", std::quoted(vw));

                    std::reverse(msg.data(), msg.data() + vw.size());

                    async_write(s, ba::buffer(msg, n), yc);
                    msg = msg.substr(n);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // a random client, let's make it connect to our own server, just for this demo
    for (auto client_id = 0; client_id<5; ++client_id) {
        spawn(io,
            [&io, delay, client_id, log=logger("client #" + std::to_string(client_id))]
            (ba::yield_context yc) {
                tcp::resolver r(io);
                tcp::socket s(io);
                async_connect(s, r.async_resolve("127.0.0.1", "6868", yc), yc);

                while (true) {
                    delay(yc);
                    ba::streambuf buf;
                    std::ostream(&buf)
                        << "Hello from client #" << client_id << "\n";

                    async_write(s, buf, yc);

                    std::string response;
                    async_read_until(s, ba::dynamic_buffer(response), "\n", yc);
                    if (!response.empty())
                        response.pop_back();

                    log("Received response ", std::quoted(response));
                }
            });
    }

    io.run_for(3s);
    logger("main")("Bye");
}
```

Comment: Great, many many thanks! From your example, I can change client port to connect to an external server in the same thread. Now I need to figure out how to handle async_read/async_write between server and client, since the communication I am trying to replicate does not look like a chat. Client will have to send periodic messages to the external server (something similar to a keep alive) and, at the same time, send data coming from an external client, so I will need to bypass messages between server and client and viceversa. Do you think I can do that keeping the single-thread logic?

Comment: @laurapons Of course. You can use shared data. And since you keep it single threaded you won't even need locking or strands

Comment: Just for fun: added a 6th client that uses shared state from the server to print statistics from the samples sent by the 5 other clients at random intervals. Now you can see statistics from shared state every second: https://wandbox.org/permlink/lbYbhDN2UwRgAwpj

Comment: Thanks for your help again! I've been trying to play around with your sample code, it really helps.

Comment: Good morning, I've been trying to modify your example with what I needed, but I struggle to enable multiple steady_timers in the client side. Here is the sample code: https://github.com/laurapons/server_client/blob/main/main.cpp (line 173). As you can see, client connects to an external server and server accepts requests from another port, once message is received from any of them, the reply will be sent to either the server or the client depending on the processing. Probably there are so many things wrong with this code... But the one I am stuck with is from line 173...

Comment: I updated the code, now it works, but I am not sure I am accessing the buffers safely... It would be great if you have some time to give some tips on how to improve it... thank you!!

Comment: Those questions might be suited for codereview.stackexchange.com