# Transforming synchronous code to async with asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm trying to convert synchronous code written with boost::asio to asynchronous.
However I'm quite confused and have a few questions.

In my synchronous code I have a socket and I'm trying to read and write from it.
I have the following things:

- a socket
- a queue for messages to write to the socket
- a queue of messages that were read from the socket
- a mutex for each of the 3 objects above

Here's what I'm doing in my synchronous code:

- thread1 is doing an infinite loop, locking the socket, read from it, unlock the socket, lock the read queue, and put the socket data in it.
- thread2 is doing an infinite loop, lock the write queue, pop the data from it, unlock the write queue, then locking the socket, write to it
- other threads can write/read messages from queues by locking the associated queue mutex, and using the queue

I'm trying to rewrite this using the async features of asio.
However it's not very clear how to do it.

- do I need to have the same io_context spread out across several threads, using a single strand ? If so, it seems that it will make everything serial, whereas in my initial code for instance the socket mutex is released just after the data is read from the socket, when we write the data to the read queue, so a "read" operation doesn't block another possible "write" operation during 100% of its execution time.
- do I need to have several io_context (one for socket, one for each queue) and have async task post from one context to the other?
- something else, but using explicit locking in my completion handler -> this seems against what async io was intended for.

Another question, but is it allowed that several threads call concurrently async methods on the same io context ? For instance, have several threads call concurently io_context.post() ? I see no mention of this in the doc, yet it's used in lots of example. Note that I'm not talking about what happens to completion handlers, but just the act of calling post()

Comment: All of the questions asked in this laundry list have been asked (many times) on this site. I suggest looking them up individually. As luck would have it, I just created a sample that might interest you and which gives you many of my recommendations in a self-contained demo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70346285/85371 (I have many more). Indeed explicit locking is anathema with Asio. The strand should do this. No need for a single strand. I usually view my strands like logical mutexes (so associated with shared state).

Comment: "I see no mention of this in the doc" - here it is https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context.thread_safety - which is conveniently linked at the bottom of https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html

Comment: @sehe thanks a lot
it seems that your first comment links to a post that does basically half-duplex (like in some asio tutorial example), ie a single strand executes all socket operations without concurrency. This is something that works but I'm wondering how it's possible to do full duplex, ie locking the socket only when it's really needed, and have the rest of the processing run concurrently when possible (for instance, storing in write buffer and poping from read buffers can be executed concurrently)

Comment: you can try my single threaded full duplex server "https://github.com/werto87/server_template.git"

Comment: @lezebulon  "a single strand executes all socket operations without concurrency". Why you say "without concurrency"?

Comment: @KoronisNeilos AFAIK running several threads with the same strand will mean that they are not executed in parallel, ie without concurrency

Comment: Please try out the examples. It is possible to write a single threaded concurrent server using boost asio.

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, concurrent == multiple threads, ie the execution can happen in parallel.

Comment: No, concurrent != multiple threads in the presence of async io. So, you can have full duplex just fine (even in single threaded code - I must have a few dozen examples of it using boost on this site). You *do* need to serialize access to the IO object though. You only need to take care of non-overlapping read/writes.

Comment: See e.g. the caveats on `async_write` (or similar composed operations): _["This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html#:~:text=This%20operation%20is,this%20operation%20completes)_

Comment: @sehe thanks, about async_write, I'm aware it can be split in different handlers, potentially overlapping. About "concurrent != multiple threads ", I'm confused now. Is it still executed in parallel ? How is parallel execution done, if not by threads?

Comment: @KoronisNeilos I'd prefer to link to much simpler code. I'm not in the mood to search deep, but here is an older answer of mine that also links to a good base full-duplex example from the Asio docs https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947058/85371

Comment: @lezebulon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O (conceptually, :galaxy-brain.jpeg: it's still threads, just not in your process, but e.g. in the kernel or in the hardware; it's the domain of IRQs, DMA and offloading and RT scheduling etc.)

Comment: @sehe thanks again. I'll probably create a new question for this because this is getting too deep into commentary, but my initial question would indeed be about several user threads.
For instance consider that in the synchronous version, a user thread can push messages to a "to send" queue, while another thread pops from a "to read" queue. There is some synchronisation when a socket sends data from the write queue, but otherwise there is parallelism. It seems that all the solutions I see with async are just about putting everything in a strand, so no more parallelism

Comment: You keep repeating the claim. I think you need to start backing it up or thinking more about the ramifications of what you've been told. Threading and asynchrony are orthogonal concepts. You can mix and match to taste.